# Deciding the threshold value in string similarity

Tags: information-retrieval

When calculating the the similarity between two strings what is the best method of deciding the threshold value ?

For en example Jaccard Coefficient how can we decide its best threshold value.

Comment: What kind of application will you use the similarity for ? It depends whether you need a fuzzy match or an exact (close to) match. Can you provide more information ?